# A 5kg object is acted on by a horizontal force, find the velocity when t = 5 seconds

Tags: calculus, physics, classical-mechanics

> A 5kg object is acted upon by a horizontal force with a magnitude given by $F=3t^{-t}+t $. If the object has an initial velocity of 5 m/s find the velocity when $t=5$ seconds.

This question was on a revision sheet given to me, I believe it revolves around Newtons second law using the formula $R=ma$. Because the object is 5 kg ,this must be the value for $m$, with 5 being the given velocity, it could possibly be derived to become acceleration, meaning it would become zero. So I think I've misinterpreted the question and I also am not sure how to approach solving velocity.

Comment: "with 5 being the R value that I think needs to be derived to become acceleration meaning it would become zero": Sorry, can you please clarify what you meant by this?

Comment: I've edited it so it makes more sense now, I mean that since velocity is just the integral of acceleration, it could possibly be derived so it can be used as a in F = ma

Answer (score 2):

You can use Newton's second law to find the acceleration with respect to time since:

$$
F(t) = ma(t)
$$

You have an expression for $F(t)$ and you also are given the mass. Once you have an expression for $a(t)$ notice that:

$$
a(t) = \frac{d}{dt}v(t)
$$

where $v(t)$ is the velocity. Thus, we have that

$$
v(t) = \int a(t) dt
$$

This will produce the velocity up to a constant of integration. You may use the initial velocity given to eliminate this.